# iif using Yes/No

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am having difficulty with a Yes/No field in a query.  My table has the Yes/No check box with a check or not, my query I am trying to run is...

```
SELECT Roster.UserID, 
EventLog.Type, 
EventLog.Priority, 
IIf([Priority]="Yes",[EventLog]![Date],Date()-183) AS Expr1
FROM EventLog 
INNER JOIN Roster 
ON EventLog.UserID = Roster.UserID
GROUP BY Roster.UserID, 
EventLog.Type, 
EventLog.Priority
HAVING (((EventLog.Type) Like "Att*"));
```

I have tried to run this as an "Expression" and as "Group by" and receive the error "Data type mismatch in criteria expression"   I am prety sure my use of the "Yes" is incorrect.  Please set me straight.

Comment: If you're using access, you should add that to the tags

Comment: Should not having be applied only to aggregate functions?

Comment: There's no aggregates, why even have the `GROUP BY` (if you're trying for unique rows, this is the appropriate time to use `DISTINCT`, or rework your query slightly).  In light of that, I'd probably swap that `HAVING` clause out for a `WHERE`, which is probably closer to what you want (note that this may not always be the case).

Comment: Asad.  Sorry for the confusion I will make sure I do that in future posts. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotation marks around the "Yes" -- with the quotes it thinks you have a string (text) value rather than a boolean (yes/no).

You might want to get in the habit of using True instead of Yes (and False instead of No) so that you'll be comfortable writing SQL for databases other than Access.

Comment: Boofus, I used your suggestion and changed "Yes" to True and it works Great!!!  Thank you!!!